# Failed Assertion

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm getting the following error where my google ads are supposed to show:

'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 241 pos 10: 'data != null'

```
}) : assert(
         data != null,
         'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.',
       ),
       textSpan = null;
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

[image: Asssetion Error]

Comment: can you include your flutter version and how you are using the widget

Comment: assert is needed to check the conditions. This part of the code says that the string passed to the text widget must not be null
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert

Comment: Just trying to work out where in my app it's used, I purchased it from codecanyon, its to do with Ad mob

Here is my flutter version

Flutter 3.3.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 135454af32 (6 weeks ago) • 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
Engine • revision 3316dd8728
Tools • Dart 2.18.6 • DevTools 2.15.0

Answer (score 1):

Text widget is getting null string, you need to provide string .

Let say you are assigning like `Text(myVariable)`. Instead of this,

- you can do a null check `if(myVariable!=null) Text(myVariable)`
- or provide default value `Text(myVariable??"got null"),`
- or  use string format `Text("${myVariable}"),`

Also, if you aren't using null-safey version, consider updating your flutter.